# Rails Dynamically Switching Static Pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I am running Rails 4 under Nginx and Phusion Passenger on my local machine to develop a web application, everything is setup and running smoothly - there were no problems.

However, when I try to view my `home` controllers `index` method, which is a `.html.erb` file, generated from `haml` via CodeKit, the page either displays nothing or the current version, and then the previous version of what I have done.

For instance:

Version 1: `<h1>Hello, World</h1>`

Version 2: `<h1>Bye, World</h1>`

If I had V1 on the sever, and update it to V2 by simply replacing the file, and refresh the page shows V2. If I refresh again it shows V1. If I refresh again it shows V2 etc…. Worse, if I manually re-type the address the page shows white, nothing, until I restart Nginx.

Is there some weird caching going on… I haven't done anything other than what is outlined in the Rails tutorial: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#hello-rails-bang

I have touched files up to stage 4.3.

This is a serious problem.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out `rack_env` was set to production, which enables `config.cache_classes`, resulting in weird page results and all of this mishap.

Setting `rack_env development` solves this issue.

Makes sense, since a deployed application won't be having pages constantly changed for .css, content or structure etc….